# Secrets Management in Azure Key Vault (SecretProviderClass)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, devops, azure-keyvault

I currently have the following configuration for the management of secrets.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-tls
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  # the data is abbreviated in this example
  tls.crt: |
        MIIC2DCCAcCgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqh ...
  tls.key: |
        MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA7yn3bRHQ5FHMQ ...
```

And this would be a pod example similar to what I have:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        # name must match the volume name below
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: /etc/secret-dir
  # The secret data is exposed to Containers in the Pod through a Volume.
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: secret-tls
```

How could I modify the configuration to have the secrets stored in Azure so that when they expire I have them already centralized in azure and I don't have to do any deploy with helm through a "SecretProviderClass" ?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results***

*I have injected the sensitive data such as tls.key, tls.cert into pods using the secret objects*

*The below command produces the two files tls.key,tls.cert*

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=foo.bar.com"
```

[image]

*We can verify that secrets are added or not*

```
kubeclt get secrets
```

*To view the YAML source of the secret*

```
kubectl get secret test-tls -o yaml
```

[image]

*Here I have used the YAML file to create the secrets*

```
vi filename.yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
    tls.crt:LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJXXXXXX
    tls.key:S0tCk1JSUV2d0lCQXXXXXX
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: test-tls
    namespace: default
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

*I have created/deployed the file using below command*

```
kubectl apply -f filename.yaml
```

*I have created the resources which is using secret values using pod YAML*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: /etc/secret-dir
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: secret-tls
```

*We can check the pods and secrets which are created or not using below command*

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl get secrets
```

[image]

*Here I have used the envFORM to store the secrets*

```
vi envpod.yaml

apiVersion: v1  
kind: Pod  
metadata:  
    name: nginx-pod  
spec:  
    containers:  
    - name: nginx-container  
       image: nginx  
        envFrom:  
        - secretRef:  
             name: secret-tls
```

*We can also check the secrets are created or not using below command*

```
kubectl get secrets
```

***Note:***

*1).Azure has the specialised driver that will map azure key vaults to secrets and allowing the rolling updates of secrets.*

*2). The best way is to store the secrets is using CSI Drivers(provider class) to store securely, if we don't want to use CSI Drivers the other option is the external secret operator you can use this link for [Refernce](https://external-secrets.io/v0.6.1/guides/templating/)*